# How to programmatically get log level in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, log4j

I need to know, programmatically in Pyspark, which is the log level.

I know I can set it, by doing:

```
# spark is a SparkSession object
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel(log_level)
```

But there is not an equivalent method for retrieving the log level.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I finally came up with a solution, by accessing the Spark session's JVM (py4j underneath):

```
def get_log_level(spark):
    log_manager = spark._jvm.org.apache.log4j.LogManager
    trace = spark._jvm.org.apache.log4j.Level.TRACE
    debug = spark._jvm.org.apache.log4j.Level.DEBUG
    info = spark._jvm.org.apache.log4j.Level.INFO
    warn = spark._jvm.org.apache.log4j.Level.WARN
    error = spark._jvm.org.apache.log4j.Level.ERROR
    fatal = spark._jvm.org.apache.log4j.Level.FATAL
    logger = log_manager.getRootLogger()

    if logger.isEnabledFor(trace):
        return "TRACE"
    elif logger.isEnabledFor(debug):
        return "DEBUG"
    elif logger.isEnabledFor(info):
        return "INFO"
    elif logger.isEnabledFor(warn):
        return "WARN"
    elif logger.isEnabledFor(error):
        return "ERROR"
    elif logger.isEnabledFor(fatal):
        return "FATAL"
    else:
        return None
```

Most probably there is a better way for doing it.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the LogLevel set in your spark session

```
log_manager = spark._jvm.org.apache.log4j.LogManager
logger = log_manager.getRootLogger().getEffectiveLevel()
```

Answer (score -1):

Spark is Open Source, right?
The source code will show you many things that are not in the documentation. And the unit tests will give you hints about things not covered in tutorials.

**Demo**: browse [the Spark project on Github](https://github.com/apache/spark/) and search for `setLogLevel`.

OK, the Github internal search usually sucks, but on a single specific keyword it's worth trying. And indeed the very 1st answer gives you this interesting snippet, from a unit test *(here reset to branch 2.4)*:

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/sql/hive-thriftserver/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveMetastoreLazyInitializationSuite.scala

```
val originalLevel = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getRootLogger().getLevel
try {
  // Avoid outputting a lot of expected warning logs
  spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("error")
...
} finally {
  spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel(originalLevel.toString)
...
}
```

---

So the `setLogLevel` method appears to be a (very) thin wrapper around the Log4J API.

And that's exactly that:

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala

```
def setLogLevel(logLevel: String) {
  ...
  Utils.setLogLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.toLevel(upperCased))
}
```

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/Utils.scala

```
def setLogLevel(l: org.apache.log4j.Level) {
  org.apache.log4j.Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(l)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I finally came up with a solution for Python (I cannot use Scala).